# QGIS not available in Pop! Linux repo so how do I install it

Tags: qgis, linux

It seems the syntax of Pop! OS is such that I can't search this site or google without it being confused as pop up.
It is a scientific based development friendly OS based on Ubuntu.
However you can't get QGIS through a repo so I wondered if anyone knows what the problem is or if there is a work around.
It seems the perfect environment for creating a python extension for QGIS so that is what  I'm trying for.

Answer (score 4):

Pop! is based on Ubuntu 18.04 so QGIS 2.18 is available by default and can be installed from the command line (or synaptic):

```
sudo apt install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

QGIS is not available via Pop!_Shop or other software centers such as Gnome Software or the Elementary App Center (which Pop!_Shop is forked from) because whoever packaged QGIS for Ubuntu (or Debian) have not included an ["appdata.xml"](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/appstream/docs/chap-Quickstart.html#sect-Quickstart-DesktopApps) file.

In order for a software center (i.e Pop!_Shop) to show an application including a description and screenshots, applications have to include a specific "appdata.xml" file.

Therefore, you'll have to install from the command line (or synaptic).

You can also install more up to date versions from QGIS:

- For the latest release QGIS 3.2 Bonn use the https://qgis.org/debian repo
- For updated point releases of the long-term support QGIS 2.18.x Las Palmas LTR use the https://qgis.org/debian-ltr repo

An example command line install based on the [provided instructions](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu):

```
REPO=https://qgis.org/debian
DISTRO=$(lsb_release -cs)

echo "deb     $REPO $DISTRO main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.list
echo "deb-src $REPO $DISTRO main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

Comment: I'm assuming since in their package manager it does not compile. it's called pop shop. I was interested in anyone with experience as to why it is not working for POP!

Comment: @Luke QGIS binaries depend on certain packages available in the main Ubuntu (or Debian) repos. I'm not sure if those are in the sources.list of a Pop!OS installation by default. And for a Xenial-based OS (not sure if this applies to the current POP!OS) you need the ubuntugis-unstable ppa to get QGIS 3.2.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, and now I see that synaptic is in Pop Shop package manager and when I use that I see that they do have QGIS for the distro.

Comment: @lewis, yes synaptic shows everything.  I use it myself.